# The "import java.util.function cannot be resolved" error

Tags: java, import, java-8

[I'm trying to run this practice script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/RosterTest.java) from the [standard Oracle Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

This seems to be a common error and I've used SO resources to make attempts to fix this. I've tried Cleaning the project, refreshing the project, switch workplace and switch back, removed and re-added the JRE7.

I don't know what else to do.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer; -----> cannot be resolved ERROR
import java.util.function.Function; -----> cannot be resolved ERROR
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.function.Predicate; -----> cannot be resolved ERROR
import java.lang.Iterable;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology; -----> cannot be resolved ERROR

public class LambdaExpressions_RosterTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you running Java 8?

Comment: All four packages come from Java 8. You need to configure SDK to reference Java 8 to fix this error.

Comment: I'm new at this. How can you tell what you are running? I'm using Eclipse Android Developer Tools...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per the [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) Javadoc,

> ```
> Since:
>       1.8
> ```

So upgrade to Java 8, or try to find an older version of the tutorial.

> I'm new at this. How can you tell what you are running? I'm using Eclipse

To determine your current Java version in eclipse, go to

```
Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details (Button in
          lower Left) -> Configuration pane
```

Look for the line `java.specification.version` - on my machine that is

```
java.specification.version=1.8
```

Or the line `java.runtime.version` - on my machine that is

```
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_11-b12
```

Comment: In Eclipse, how can I tell what Java I'm running?

Comment: I'm running, Eclipse with ADT. It's different from those steps. I'm digging at this now...

Comment: Right click on project, then properties, then Java Compiler, and note the "Compiler compliance level". If you don't see 1.8 available, install it first, then add it to Eclipse, and then it'll be available to you.

Comment: I run a plain Windows 32 bit machine. Any advice which 1.8 to install? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Comment: @StacyM Windows x86 - the Offline version can be used to save yourself a lot of time if you're installing on multiple machines, the Online version downloads the Java installation content dynamically during installation.

Comment: Ok, installed 1.8. Any tips on "add it to Eclipse"? When I go to Window - Preferences - Java - Compiler - Compiler Compliance Level, it doesn't show as available.

Comment: Figured it out! Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs - Add Standard VM - path to C: Program Files\Java\jre8.

Answer (score 15):

i solved this problem by trying following solution

Project > Properties > Java Build Path
Select Libraries tab
Select  JRE System Library
Click Edit button
Choose an alternate JRE (jre1.8.0_20)
Click Finish button

Comment: Saved me, I struggled serious 3 hours, solved using your above given suggestion, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

Lambda Expressions are newly added into Java 8. They are not available for JRE7.
Try to upgrade your eclipse project's JRE to 8 (window -> preferences->java->compiler).

Answer (score 1):

For idea IntelliJ you need to go to Menu-> Project Structure -> Module here you will see Source tab, above this tab you can see language level. change it to more than 8.

-yash

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar with Apache Camel: 
the following function was not working anymore

```
String headerKey = exchange.getIn().getHeader("headerKey",String.class);
```

because of the error-message:

```
The type java.util.function.Supplier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

To solve the issue I change the casting and it worked afterwards:

```
String headerKey = (String) exchange.getIn().getHeader("headerKey");
```

maybe it helps you or somebody else.

One other point to mention here would be the Apache Camel version itself as stated on the official page [linked here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/what-are-the-dependencies.html).

Answer (score 0):

same problem is coming to me,I make a changes in eclipse.ini file and
did -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8 instead of -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
and my problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem when the version I was using in the below properties was <1.8. Updating my POM to a version >1.8 resolved my issue.

```
<properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while trying to use Java 9 with Eclipse Oxygen. Eclipse claimed that I was using less than Java 1.8 and asked if I wanted to use 1.8. Saying yes solved the problem, but led to this error message later on.

I went in to Window => Preferences => Java => Compiler and saw that this had been changed to 1.8, so I changed it back to 9 and everything seems to be working now.