# import java.util.arrays is not resolved

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, import

I'm a new student in computer science learning Java and using Eclipse and we are now working on arrays but when I tried to practice arrays on my own time did I discover that something was wrong when I imported the Arrays class.

Eclipse said *The import java.util.Arrays; cannot be resolved*.

I've checked the solutions provided already and it did not help. I have configured a new build path (JRE System Library JRE 1.8.0-60) and have set it to both Alternate JRE and Workspace Default and have even downloaded the newest Java Runtime Environment as well a fresh download of Eclipse but nothing is working.

Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT 1:** Yes I have used Project>Clean, it didn't work.

**EDIT 2:** I am using Eclipse Helios and I've run it in a online IDE and it works fine. But NOT in Eclipse for some reason.

Code (note: I worked on this at school and it was fine. On my own computer is where the problem came up):

```
import java.util.Arrays;



public class Chap7Practice {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] deck = new String[52];

    final String [] Suits = {"Spades",  "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts" };
    final String [] Ranks = { "Ace","two", "three", "four", "five","six", "seven", 
            "eight", "nine","ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};


    int counter = 0;
    for(int s= 0; s<Suits.length; s++){
        for(int r = 0; r<Ranks.length; r++){
            String card = Ranks[r] + " of " + Suits[s];
            deck[counter] = card;
            ++counter;
        }
    }

    String [] deck2; //not a good way to copy =deck;
    deck2 = new String[52];
    for(int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++){
        deck2[i] = deck[i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deck));

}



}
```

Comment: It works for me on my computer. Do you have `path` environment variable properly configured?

Comment: Remove the unnecessary code from the post.

Comment: @Frakcool path environment variable? Can you explain? I'm very new to programming.

Comment: Are you working on Ubuntu / Windows?

Comment: You mentioned about installing new JRE, what about JDK?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse error: "The import XXX cannot be resolved"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322893/eclipse-error-the-import-xxx-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Open Explorer (for God's sake not IE!), then go to your `JDK/bin` folder and copy the path. After that right clic on "My PC" -> Properties -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables -> Add a new variable called `JAVA_HOME` and paste your `JDK/bin` path -> Edit `Path` variable **but DON'T delete anything** -> Add `;%JAVA_HOME%;` after all variable value.

Comment: @Frakcool did all that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried compiling through console? (i.e. `CMD`) ?

Comment: @Frakcool I've compiled it in an online IDE and it works but I need it to work in Eclipse since that is the one we will be using in class.

Comment: Were you able to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

- Right click on project
- Select BuildPath
- Select Configure BuildPath
- Select Libraries tab
- Then Double clickon JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY
- Then select alternate JRE

It should work.

### See Also

- [The “import java.util.function cannot be resolved” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129781/the-import-java-util-function-cannot-be-resolved-error)

Comment: I tried that like I said in the original post, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the Eclipse version I had and somehow I had downloaded the wrong one. I did a fresh install which was exactly the same but it works now. I am not exactly sure what happened because I go through the same installer that is on the Eclipse website so what down the line caused the problem is still a mystery to me.